# Apple LLVM 6.0 Error Clang 254

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, xcode6

Running Xcode 6.1 on Mavericks, is this an xcode issue? or something I did

Sorry, I know posting these errors must get annoying, I tried googling around but couldn't find a solution that works

This would happen whether I was running a unmodified template xcode file or something that I tried to code myself. :(

Thanks,
Joe

```
CompileC /Users/joe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pac-dmdcvwzinfweyzgefcqbhztzjxfl/Build/Intermediates/pac.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/pac.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o pac/main.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
cd /Users/joe/Desktop/pac
export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/joe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1 -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -mios-simulator-version-min=8.1 -iquote /Users/joe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pac-dmdcvwzinfweyzgefcqbhztzjxfl/Build/Intermediates/pac.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/pac.build/pac-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/joe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pac-dmdcvwzinfweyzgefcqbhztzjxfl/Build/Intermediates/pac.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/pac.build/pac-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/joe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pac-dmdcvwzinfweyzgefcqbhztzjxfl/Build/Intermediates/pac.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/pac.build/pac-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/joe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pac-dmdcvwzinfweyzgefcqbhztzjxfl/Build/Intermediates/pac.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/pac.build/pac-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/joe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pac-dmdcvwzinfweyzgefcqbhztzjxfl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Users/joe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pac-dmdcvwzinfweyzgefcqbhztzjxfl/Build/Intermediates/pac.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/pac.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/joe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pac-dmdcvwzinfweyzgefcqbhztzjxfl/Build/Intermediates/pac.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/pac.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/joe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pac-dmdcvwzinfweyzgefcqbhztzjxfl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/joe/Desktop/pac/parse-library-1 -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/joe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pac-dmdcvwzinfweyzgefcqbhztzjxfl/Build/Intermediates/pac.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/pac.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/joe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pac-dmdcvwzinfweyzgefcqbhztzjxfl/Build/Intermediates/pac.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/pac.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.dia -c /Users/joe/Desktop/pac/pac/main.m -o /Users/joe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pac-dmdcvwzinfweyzgefcqbhztzjxfl/Build/Intermediates/pac.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/pac.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
```

Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-ios8.1.0 -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name main.m -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-cpu core2 -target-linker-version 241.9 -gdwarf-2 -coverage-file /Users/joe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pac-dmdcvwzinfweyzgefcqbhztzjxfl/Build/Intermediates/pac.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/pac.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/6.0 -dependency-file /Users/joe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pac-dmdcvwzinfweyzgefcqbhztzjxfl/Build/Intermediates/pac.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/pac.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.d -MT dependencies -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk -iquote /Users/joe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pac-dmdcvwzinfweyzgefcqbhztzjxfl/Build/Intermediates/pac.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/pac.build/pac-generated-files.hmap -iquote /Users/joe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pac-dmdcvwzinfweyzgefcqbhztzjxfl/Build/Intermediates/pac.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/pac.build/pac-project-headers.hmap -D DEBUG=1 -D NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1 -D OBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES=0 -I /Users/joe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pac-dmdcvwzinfweyzgefcqbhztzjxfl/Build/Intermediates/pac.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/pac.build/pac-own-target-headers.hmap -I /Users/joe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pac-dmdcvwzinfweyzgefcqbhztzjxfl/Build/Intermediates/pac.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/pac.build/pac-all-target-headers.hmap -I /Users/joe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pac-dmdcvwzinfweyzgefcqbhztzjxfl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I /Users/joe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pac-dmdcvwzinfweyzgefcqbhztzjxfl/Build/Intermediates/pac.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/pac.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I /Users/joe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pac-dmdcvwzinfweyzgefcqbhztzjxfl/Build/Intermediates/pac.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/pac.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/joe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pac-dmdcvwzinfweyzgefcqbhztzjxfl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/joe/Desktop/pac/parse-library-1 -O0 -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -Wno-trigraphs -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=objc-root-class -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-sign-conversion -std=gnu99 -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/joe/Desktop/pac -ferror-limit 19 -fmacro-backtrace-limit 0 -fmessage-length 0 -stack-protector 1 -mstackrealign -fblocks -fmodules -fmodules-cache-path=/Users/joe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -fmodules-prune-interval=86400 -fmodules-prune-after=345600 -fobjc-runtime=ios-8.1.0 -fencode-extended-block-signature -fobjc-arc -fobjc-exceptions -fexceptions -fpascal-strings -fdiagnostics-show-option -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fasm-blocks -vectorize-slp -serialize-diagnostic-file /Users/joe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pac-dmdcvwzinfweyzgefcqbhztzjxfl/Build/Intermediates/pac.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/pac.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.dia -o /Users/joe/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/pac-dmdcvwzinfweyzgefcqbhztzjxfl/Build/Intermediates/pac.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/pac.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o -x objective-c /Users/joe/Desktop/pac/pac/main.m 
1.   parser at end of file
2.  Code generation
3.  Running pass 'Function Pass Manager' on module '/Users/joe/Desktop/pac/pac/main.m'.
4.  Running pass 'X86 DAG->DAG Instruction Selection' on function '@main'
clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
clang: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.54) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
Thread model: posix
clang: note: diagnostic msg: PLEASE submit a bug report to http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/ and include the crash backtrace, preprocessed source, and associated run script.
clang: note: diagnostic msg:

---

PLEASE ATTACH THE FOLLOWING FILES TO THE BUG REPORT:
Preprocessed source(s) and associated run script(s) are located at:
clang: note: diagnostic msg: /var/folders/3r/jfx826nx1yvd_xxd03fxdk580000gn/T/main-df87ab.m
clang: note: diagnostic msg: /var/folders/3r/jfx826nx1yvd_xxd03fxdk580000gn/T/main-df87ab.cache
clang: note: diagnostic msg: /var/folders/3r/jfx826nx1yvd_xxd03fxdk580000gn/T/main-df87ab.sh
clang: note: diagnostic msg:

---

Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 254

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can follow [this example](http://myioslearning.blogspot.com/2014/12/how-to-remove-apple-llvm-60-error-ios.html) to solve this issue. It worked for me. You have to delete the derived data and the restart xCode. It always work with Apple LLVM 6.0 Error.